# select item in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

in this for loop  why not loop all the input ?

I tried in jquery each it work..  but I want use for loop do I miss something

I want to add class to all input not has class `.typeLimit` , and select item in the loop

https://jsfiddle.net/6v8arLqa/

```
var type = 'number';

for (var i = 0; i < $('input[data-type-limit="' + type + '"]').not('.typeLimit').length; i++) {
    console.log(i)
    var input = $('input[data-type-limit="' + type + '"]').not('.typeLimit').eq(i);
    console.log(input)
    input.addClass('typeLimit');
 }


<input type="text" data-type-limit="number" placeholder=":1">
<input type="text" data-type-limit="number" placeholder=":2">
<input type="text" data-type-limit="number" placeholder=":3">
<input type="text" data-type-limit="number" placeholder=":4">
<input type="text" data-type-limit="number" placeholder=":5">
<input type="text" data-type-limit="number" placeholder=":6">
<input type="text" data-type-limit="number" placeholder=":7">
<input type="text" data-type-limit="number" placeholder=":8">
<input type="text" data-type-limit="number" placeholder=":9">
<input type="text" data-type-limit="number" placeholder=":10">
```

test with each

```
$.each($('input[data-type-limit="' + type + '"]').not('.typeLimit'), function(i, val) {
console.log(i)
      var input = $(this);
      input.addClass('typeLimit');
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because every time you go through the loop, the contents of `$('input[data-type-limit="' + type + '"]').not('.typeLimit')` are changing so you're going to skip some elements. To prevent this problem (and be much more efficient) you can cache the results and work through those.

```
var $noTypeLimit = $('input[data-type-limit="' + type + '"]').not('.typeLimit');
for (var i = 0; i < $noTypeLimit.length; i++) {
  var $input = $noTypeLimit.eq(i);
  $input.addClass('typeLimit');
}
```

Or if all you're doing is adding a class to them, you can simplify it even more.

```
$('input[data-type-limit="' + type + '"]')
  .not('.typeLimit')
  .addClass('typeLimit');
```

Comment: thanks for reply, it works I use first method cache them, if I doing this is there any different performance compare with jquery each

Comment: This way is faster than either of the other options. You save yourself additional DOM queries and you don't have to perform a bunch of other function calls.